# typescript vs2013 intellisense problems

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013

I'm still having problems with implicit referencing not working...

I created a new MVC project.

I added Angular.Typescript.DefinitelyTyped

I added a typescript file TestApp.ts and create a small class TestCtrl (under 
scripts\modules\testapp\TestApp.ts)

In the same file I write : angular.module("TestApp",[]).controller("TestCtrl",TestCtrl);

At this point I have intellisense working.

Then I close the solution, open the solution again, open TestApp.ts and in the line containing "angular.module", angular is show with squiggly lines, Hovering over ,shows angular is not defined.

Normally all ts files should be implicitely referenced?

All typescript files in csproj are added with <TypeScriptCompile Include ...

I have reference to `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" />`

TscToolPath contains path to version 1.0

```
<TscToolPath Condition="'$(TscToolPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0</TscToolPath>
```

Also what is see ,is when typescript virtual projects are enabled I'm only seeing the files opened in this project, normally it should show all typescript files?

Comment: At the top of the typescript file, do you have the /// <reference path="path/to/library" /> tag?

Comment: normally the typescript documentation mentions that all.ts and .d.ts files should be implicity referenced see https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20breaking%20changes%20between%200.8%20and%200.9
In Visual Studio, all TypeScript files in a project are considered to be referencing each other

Answer (score 0):

VS2013 update 3 solved all problems...